# Existence of a map via universal property?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A,B$ be subspaces of $X.$ Let $C \subseteq A \cap B.$ Let $f : A \longrightarrow B$ be a map. Then does it necessarily induce a map $\widetilde {f} : A/C \longrightarrow B/C\ $? If not, then what are the criterions the map $f$ should satisfy to induce the map $\widetilde f\ $?

**EDIT** $:$ I think if $f$ maps $C$ homeomorphically onto $C$ then we can have such maps by universal property of quotient topology. In fact then the map will be one-one and onto.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the canonical quotient maps $\pi_A:  A\to A/C$ and $\pi_B :B\to B/C$. From $f$ we get a map $\pi_B\circ f : A\to B/C$. This induces a map $A/C\to B/C$ if, and only if, $\pi_B\circ f$ is constant on $C$. We see that this is the case if, and only if, one of the following holds :

1. $f|_C$ is constant ;

*or*

2. $f(C) \subset C$

Comment: How do you get that map $A \xrightarrow {\pi_B\ \circ\ f} B/C$ will induce a map $A/C \rightarrow B/C$ if and only if $\pi_B \circ f$ is constant on $C\ $? I don't get your argument anywhere in Munkres' book.

Comment: Universal property of the quotient

Comment: Have you seen Munkres' book? There I found something different.

Comment: Could you include in the OP what you found there ?

Comment: I am actually trying to use corollary $22.3$ of Munkres.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the corollary I am referring to.

Comment: Thx for the screen shot. Theorem 22.2 is the universal property of the quotient, which answers your question. Corollary 22.3 is saying that $g:X\to Z$ is a quotient map iff $Z$ is the quotient space of $X$ under some equivalence relation. This is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: No you are misinterpreting the result. This is a consequence of universal property which I find more helpful. It says that when the surjective map $g : X \longrightarrow Z$ induces a map $\widetilde {g} : X^* \longrightarrow Z\ $? Where $X^*$ is the collection of fibres of $f$ equipped with quotient topology. In this case $g = \pi_B\ \circ\ f.$ We need to show that the fibres of this map is precisely $A/C.$

Comment: Can you please provide the universal property you are using? Thanks.

Comment: I get your point. Thanks.